# do while cycle with a try catch asking to return value

Tags: c#

im having issues with returning the desired value of x while its true to the if statement and otherwise would just start the do while cycle again, but my method is asking for a return value in catch parts of my code. Im trying to make a game where the player can input a value and the called method returns the value after its exceptions have been handled (in case the player inputs anything but an int, he gets an error message and is asked to try again).

Heres the code:

```
static int inputHumanCount()
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Input the number of people you want (current limit is 10000)");
        bool key = true;
        do
        {
            try
            {
                int x = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                if(x >= 1 && x <= 10000)
                {
                    key = false;
                    return x;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Wrong number");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Wrong number");
            }
        } while (key == true);
```

Comment: While this code isn't elegant the only "error" I see is that if you input an invalid value it will not print the prompt again, just wait for more input.  What is it doing wrong?

Comment: The program is throwing me an error saying not all code paths return a value and if i use return 0 in else and catch the program just stops basically when i type in a character for example.

Comment: Oh, I see what it's squawking about--if it were to escape the loop (it can't, but the compiler doesn't know that) there's no return value.  Get rid of that key value, do while (true);

Answer (score 1):

You could return the result after the do-while loop.

For example,

```
static int inputHumanCount()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Input the number of people you want (current limit is 10000)");
    int result = -1;

    bool key = true;
    do
    {
        try
        {
            result = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            if (result >= 1 && result <= 10000)
            {
                key = false;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Wrong number");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Wrong number");
        }
    } while (key == true);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Problem with this is that the user inputs the data before the loop meaning you only get one shot at inputing x in this case.

Comment: I forgot it... updated my answer. You need to give return value on exception and on `else` block

Comment: You don't really need the break here (it's not an error though)

Answer (score 1):

Never *ever* use `Convert` style methods or *exceptions* to validate *user input*.

Convert style methods throw and *exception* should not be use to control the flow of a process.

Instead user `TryParse` style methods.

[Int32.TryParse Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=net-5.0)

> Converts the string representation of a number to its 32-bit signed
> integer equivalent. A return value indicates whether the operation
> succeeded.

You could also do this succinctly in the while loop

```
Console.WriteLine("Input the number of people you want (current limit is 10000)");

string input = null;
int val = 0;
while (!int.TryParse(input = Console.ReadLine(),out val) || val < 1 || val > 10000)
   Console.WriteLine($"Does this look like a number between 1 and 10000 to you? : {input}");

Console.WriteLine($"Game over you won : number = {val}");
```

**Output**

```
Input the number of people you want (current limit is 10000)
x
Does this look like a number between 1 and 10000 to you? : x
1231312
Does this look like a number between 1 and 10000 to you? : 1231312
10
Game over you won : number = 10
```

Note the point here isn't the code, it's to use `TryParse` to validate input.

Comment: Not quite what i was looking for but thanks for the TryParse usage ill keep that in mind ! Only programming for a month so many many errors here.

Answer (score 0):

You should return 0 in your code after do while loop, if you want to keep asking user to input some number and check if input was correct.
Check this code:

```
static int inputHumanCount()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Input the number of people you want (current limit is 10000)");
    bool key = true;
    do
    {
       try
       {
           int x = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
           if (x >= 1 && x <= 10000)
           {
              key = false;
              return x;
           }
           else
           {
              Console.WriteLine("Wrong number");
           }
       }
       catch (Exception)
       {
           Console.WriteLine("Wrong number");
       }
   } while (key == true);

    return 0;
}
```